# Is it inevitable that SWT is a dependency in an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, swt, eclipse-rcp

Say, I have an application based on the e4 platform using pure **JavaFX** instead of **SWT** as a rendering technology, like [this one](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial3). Does it still need some SWT libraries indirectly? After all, the Eclipse platform is based on SWT. Am I understanding it the right way?  I can't see any direct dependencies from the **Dependencies** tab as following though.

[image]

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The core of Eclipse 4 is not based on SWT. The UI toolkit used for Eclipse is defined by a set of renderers. Each renderer is responsible for showing a particular object from the application model (part stack, toolbar, and so on).

The standard renderers use SWT but e(fx)clipse changes this to a set using JavaFX.

A single renderer factory is used to create all these renderers. The renderer factory is defined by the `rendererFactoryUri` property of the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point.

This only applies to the Eclipse core, lots of Eclipse plug-ins are coded using SWT directly and would have to be rewritten to use JavaFX.